# Apache rewrite: Strip out url part

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have a Ruby on Rails app with two sub-sites, `www.example.com/site1` and `www.example.com/site2`. For demonstration purpose, we need to disable `site2` and only show `site1`. So I made some redirects in my apache virtual host conf like this

```
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/site2 http://www.example.com/site1
Redirect 301 http://www.example.com http://www.example.com/site1
```

to be sure to always redirect to `site1`. Now, it would be great, if we could kinda strip out the `site1` from the url `http://www.example.com/site1` so that it only shows `http://www.example.com`, but also can handle sub sites (e.g. the "original" site is `http://www.example.com/site1/cat1` and it should be displayed as `http://www.example.com/cat1`).

- Is this possible using apache's rewrite engine? And how?
- I'm not sure if I have to change something inside my app, or is the request URL (that my router picks up) not modified by apache?
- Another solution would be, to only show the domain in the users address bar. Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like you should just change the DocumentRoot for www.example.com to the `site1` directory instead of what it is now. That obviates the need for redirection in all three of your cited examples.

Comment: Nope, that won't work, because the underlying app is a Ruby on Rails application, which doesn't have any folder like structure, just a router. But we don't want to change anything on the app, because it's just for a one-time demonstration